# JS: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: angular, autocomplete, nativescript

I have a question about my code.

I want to use this autocomplete in my project for country [plugin](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/master/autocomplete/app/item/items.component.ts)

I get all country in JSON like below:

```
JS: country [{
JS:   "name": "Afghanistan",
JS:   "short_name": "AF",
JS:   "country_id": 1
JS: }, {
JS:   "name": "Albania",
JS:   "short_name": "AL",
JS:   "country_id": 2
JS: }, {
JS:   "name": "Algeria",
JS:   "short_name": "DZ",
JS:   "country_id": 3
JS: }, {
JS:   "name": "American Samoa",
JS:   "short_name": "AS",
JS:   "country_id": 4
JS: }, {
JS:   "name": "Andorra",
JS:   "short_name": "AD",
JS:   "country_id": 5
JS: },{
JS:   "...}]
```

In service I call function like in this code:

```
 public getAllCountryws(): Observable<Country[]> {
        return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.countryGetAll), {
        })
            .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
                let res = response.json();
                if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
                    this.auth.logout();
                } else if (res.StatusCode === 4) {
                    return false;
                } else if (res.StatusDescription === 'No result') {
                    return false;
                } else if (res.StatusDescription === '[]') {
                    return false;
                } else if (res.StatusDescription === []) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return res.StatusDescription.map(country => {
                        return new Country(country);
                    });
                }
            },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }))
    }
```

And in component.ts I call service function like in this code:

```
public country: Country[] = [];
  private _items: ObservableArray<TokenModel>;
   @ViewChild("autocomplete") autocomplete: RadAutoCompleteTextViewComponent;

   ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getallcountry();
    }
    getallcountry() {
        this.ws.getAllCountryws().subscribe(
            country => {
                this.country = country;
                const mycountry = country;
                console.log('mycountry', mycountry) // show correct JSON
                 for (let i = 0; i < mycountry.length; i++) {
                console.log(mycountry.length) // show correct
                     this._items.push(new TokenModel(mycountry[i].company_id, null));
                }
            },
            err => console.error('err', err),
            () => console.log('error')
        );
    }
```

ERROR:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2MNQ.png)

Also, in html I have this code:

```
            <Label text="Select Country*" row="0" col='0'></Label>
            <RadAutoCompleteTextView #autocomplete [items]="_items" suggestMode="Suggest" displayMode="Tokens"
                row="1" col='0' hint="Country">
                <SuggestionView tkAutoCompleteSuggestionView>
                    <ng-template tkSuggestionItemTemplate let-item="item">
                        <StackLayout orientation="vertical" padding="10">
                            <Label [text]="item.name"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ng-template>
                </SuggestionView>
            </RadAutoCompleteTextView>
```

In view, doesn't show nothing. No results found.

Update:
From :       `private _items: ObservableArray<TokenModel>;`

To:          `public _items: TokenModel[] = [];`

Add:

```
   get dataItems():  TokenModel[] {
        console.log('this._items', this._items)
        return this._items;
    }
```

[Error with result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S7vB.png)

In html change:

from:   `<RadAutoCompleteTextView #autocomplete [items]="_items" suggestMode="Suggest" displayMode="Tokens"`

to:

```
 <RadAutoCompleteTextView #autocomplete [items]="dataItems" suggestMode="Suggest" displayMode="Tokens"
```

**In view doesn't show any results.**

Comment: check this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856647/angular-6-rxjs-6-0-how-to-push-new-element-to-array-contained-by-observable

Comment: Yes I read this article, but I think that a problem maybe is in xml code. Because I show data in console. Can you see again please?

Answer (score 2):

In your component.ts file change the `_items` declaration

From:

```
private _items: ObservableArray<TokenModel>;
```

To:

```
private _items: TokenModel[] = [];
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I change show: Type 'undefined[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ObservableArray<TokenModel>': on, getItem, setItem, once, and 8 more.

Comment: @eg16 this is not how you initialise a  ObservableArray

Comment: @AlonBi
private _items: TokenModel[];

Comment: JS: ERROR TypeError: this.items.getItem is not a function. In view doesn't show country